# Why I need Group by in this simple query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**UPDATE :**

**-----**

the error might be in sum(si.amt_pd) from item table (as there is no relation) :

```
select SUM(si.amt_pd)amt_pd from [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.item  i
                    where
```

is there a work around?

**----------**

I am trying to run this query. The query just fetches the amount of a month based on some tables. It is just a part of a big query.

```
select s.sales_Contract_Nbr
     , s.Sales_Id
     , s.Sale_Dt
     , YEAR(s.Sale_Dt) 'YEAR'
     , MONTH(s.Sale_Dt) 'MONTH'
     , s.Sales_Need_TYpe_Cd
     , s.Sales_Status_Cd
     , si.Posted
     , s.location_Cd
     , jan2011 = (
          select SUM(si.amt_pd)amt_pd 
          from [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.item  i
          where i.Item_Id  = si.Product_Item_ID
            and i.Item_Cd <> '*INT'
            and convert(varchar(10),SI.Sales_Item_Dt,126) >= '2011-01-01'   
            and convert(varchar(10),SI.Sales_Item_Dt,126) >= '2011-01-31'
            ) INTO dbo.#a_acomparision

FROM [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales S 
   , [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales_Item SI 

WHERE SI.Sales_Id = S.Sales_Id 
  and s.Sales_Contract_Nbr in (
      select distinct (Sales_Contract_Nbr) 
      from mountainviewContracts 
      where Sales_Contract_Nbr <> '')
```

but I am getting the following error message.

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'HMIS_REPORTING.HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales.Sales_Contract_Nbr' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I just can't understand why my query should have a group by for sales_contract_nbr and even if I put in the group by clause it tells me that inner query si.Product_item_id and SI.sales_item_dt should also be contained in group by clause.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you haven't shown us your complete query. I assume there already exists a group by.

Comment: *"It is just a part of a big query."* It looks as though the part of the query causing the problem has been omitted - this error message would only be returned where there is either a GROUP BY clause after the main query, or where the SELECT clause already includes an aggregate function. Can you include the rest of the query?

Comment: Isn't there any more rows or executions in the query? I tried to run it but it seemed to work

Comment: @DanielHilgarth  by the line "big query" I meant similar jan2011, feb2011, mar2011 query all containing the same code with different dates. There is no group by clause other than this query.

Comment: Why are you using `INTO dbo.#a_acomparision` after the subquery? You want those row to be inserted in the table?

Comment: @LeandroBarreto yes I will then use this table for joins. It seams that the error is here : select SUM(si.amt_pd)amt_pd from [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.item  i

Comment: I think the query optimizer will re-write your query to turn the subquery into a regular (sum) statement, and that in turn will require a group by. Have you tried adding the group by at the end of the query?

Comment: @NevilleK yes i did for sales_contract_nbr but then it tells me to add group by for sales_item_dt , product_item

Answer (score 1):

This is a very subtle problem.  However, I think the subquery should be:

```
select SUM(i.amt_pd)amt_pd from [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.item  i
```

That is, the alias should be `i` not `si`.

What is happening is that the `sum` in the subquery is on a value in the outer query.  So, the SQL compiler assumes an aggregation query.  As soon as the first column is found that is not an aggregation, it complains with the message that you have.

By the way, you should use proper join syntax, so you `from` clause looks like:

```
FROM [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales S join
     [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales_Item SI 
     on SI.Sales_Id = S.Sales_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff says, this is almost certainly because the query optimizer is treating this like a SUM operation, normalizing away the subquery for "jan2001".

If the amt_pd column is present in the ITEM table, Gordon's solution is the right one.

If not, you have to add the group by statement, as below.

```
select s.sales_Contract_Nbr
     , s.Sales_Id
     , s.Sale_Dt
     , YEAR(s.Sale_Dt) 'YEAR'
     , MONTH(s.Sale_Dt) 'MONTH'
     , s.Sales_Need_TYpe_Cd
     , s.Sales_Status_Cd
     , si.Posted
     , s.location_Cd
     , jan2011 = (
          select SUM(si.amt_pd)amt_pd 
          from [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.item  i
          where i.Item_Id  = si.Product_Item_ID
            and i.Item_Cd <> '*INT'
            and convert(varchar(10),SI.Sales_Item_Dt,126) >= '2011-01-01'   
            and convert(varchar(10),SI.Sales_Item_Dt,126) >= '2011-01-31'
            ) INTO dbo.#a_acomparision

FROM [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales S 
   , [HMIS_REPORTING].HMIS_RPT_ME.dbo.Sales_Item SI 

WHERE SI.Sales_Id = S.Sales_Id 
  and s.Sales_Contract_Nbr in (
      select distinct (Sales_Contract_Nbr) 
      from mountainviewContracts 
      where Sales_Contract_Nbr <> '')
GROUP BY s.sales_Contract_Nbr
     , s.Sales_Id
     , s.Sale_Dt
     , YEAR
     , MONTH
     , s.Sales_Need_TYpe_Cd
     , s.Sales_Status_Cd
     , si.Posted
     , s.location_Cd
```